# bash redirection again: question hard time understanding 2 similar commands

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I would appreciate somebody explaining please why the following *does* work:

```
# < /dev/urandom  tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | head -c 12
```

There is no '|' before *tr* , but the following doesn't:

```
# < /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | head -c 12
```

(This is a simple password generator)

Could you also please explain how that differs to the following:

`# gunzip < HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz  cat >  ouT1`  --- which of course fails:

```
gzip: cat.gz: No such file or directory
```

if the '|' is left out before the cat; it works however, with the '|' (pipe) before the `cat` , i.e.

```
 # gunzip < HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz | cat >  ouT1
```

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. **What is `<`?**

   It is redirection of command's INPUT to read FROM a file. You can put it either before or after command:

   ```
   $ echo abcd > in
   $ cat in
   abcd
   $ cat <in
   abcd
   $ <in cat
   abcd
   ```

   In simple terms, the command reads the file. The difference between `cat in` and `cat <in` is that `<` sets a redirection of STDIN (standard input) for the `cat` process, while in `cat in` the `in` is an argument, and the `cat` command has to do something with it internally. (Open it, then read it, etc.)
2. **What is `|`?**

   It is redirection to a process. It can only follow a command:

   ```
   $ | cat in
   bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
   $ cat in | cat
   abcd
   $ cat in | cat |
   >
   ```

   (...and waiting for input...)
3. What does this do: `< /dev/urandom  tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | head -c 12`?

   Break it down into smaller pieces (commands with redirections):

   - `< /dev/urandom  tr -dc 'a-zA-Z'` = `tr -dc 'a-zA-Z'` and `< /dev/urandom`

     Meaning: do the translation for what you read from `urandom`.
   - `|` - redirect to a process using an anonymous pipe
   - `head -c 12` - this is the process receiving the redirection

   The whole line makes sense, doesn't it?
4. What is this: `< /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | head -c 12`?

   Break-down:

   - `< /dev/urandom` - **no command** and redirection from `/dev/urandom`
   - `|` - redirect to a process using an anonymous pipe
   - `tr -dc 'a-zA-Z'` - the process receiving the redirection
   - and so on...

   What's wrong here? There's no command in the first "sentence".
5. **What is `>`?**

   This is a redirection of this command's OUTPUT TO a file. Same as `<`, it can be used before or after a command:

   ```
   $ >out echo abcd
   $ cat out
   abcd
   $ echo dcba >tuo
   $ cat tuo
   dcba
   ```
6. What's this supposed to do: `gunzip < HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz | cat >  ouT1`?

   Analysis:

   - `gunzip < HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz` = redirect from `HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz` to `gunzip` (let `gunzip` read this file)
   - `|` - redirect the output to a process
   - `cat > ouT1` = `cat` is the process to receive the redirection and then it's output is redirected to the file `ouT1`

   This is fine. All the pieces make sense.
7. What is this then: `gunzip < HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz  cat >  ouT1`?

   I'm not 100% sure how this is interpreted by all involved parties here, but let's speculate. The error is this:

   ```
   gzip: cat.gz: No such file or directory
   ```

   The first word in this error is `gzip`, so we know gzip has run. Also we know (at least I do), that the redirections are set by the sell before the command is interpreted. So I analyse it this way:

   - `< HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz` - shell sets the process INPUT redirection to `HP-Fax4-hpcups.ppd.gz`, ie. the command to be executed will read from this file
   - `>  ouT1` - the OUTPUT of the command is to be redirected TO `ouT1`

   So far so good. What's left on the table now is this: `gunzip cat`. The standard interpretation of this is that `gunzip` is a command and `cat` is its argument. So now `gunzip` runs (with both IN and OUT redirections set), and it gets the string `cat` as its first argument. And somehow it throws the error:

   ```
   gzip: cat.gz: No such file or directory
   ```

   What does it mean, again? It's `gzip` saying that it can't find `cat.gz`. It wants to do something with it (most likely open it), and there's no such file or directory. Thus must be a matter of its internals why it makes `cat.gz` out of `cat` it got as an argument. A simple experiment reveals that it expects the argument to be in gzip format:

   ```
   $ echo asdf > cat.gz
   $ gunzip < in  cat >  ouT1

   gzip: cat.gz: not in gzip format
   ```

   The `in` file here is a simple text file, so hence the blank line, I gather.